# If $X$ is a conformal Killing vector field, what is $\nabla_X \text{Rc}$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, conformal-geometry

Suppose
$$
\nabla_a X_b+ \nabla_b X_a = \Omega g_{ab}
$$
for some smooth, positive function $\Omega$ on a (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$. Can one find a nice expression, independent of $X$, for $\nabla_X \text{Rc}$ where $\text{Rc}$ is the Ricci tensor?
I thought of trying the following, first recalling that

\begin{align}
  \mathcal{L}_X \text{Rc} (Y, Z) &= X (\text{Rc}(Y, Z)) - \text{Rc}([X, Y], Z) - \text{Rc}(Y, [X, Z])
  \\
  &= X (\text{Rc}(Y, Z)) - \text{Rc}(\nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X, Z) - \text{Rc}(Y, \nabla_X Z -
    \nabla_Z X)
  \\
  &= X (\text{Rc}(Y, Z)) - \text{Rc}(\nabla_X Y, Z) + \text{Rc}(\nabla_Y X, Z) - \text{Rc}(Y, \nabla_X
    Z) +\text{Rc}(Y, 
    \nabla_Z X)
  \\
  &= \nabla_X \text{Rc}(Y, Z) + \text{Rc}(\nabla_Y X, Z) + \text{Rc}(Y, \nabla_Z X)
\end{align}
so it suffices to compute $\mathcal L_X \text{Rc}$ and $\text{Rc}(\nabla_Y X, Z) + \text{Rc}(Y, \nabla_Z X)$. It seems like computing the Lie derivative should be doable by looking at formulas for conformal transformations of metrics, but the $\text{Rc}(\nabla_Y X, Z) + \text{Rc}(Y, \nabla_Z X)$ term eludes me. Is such a simplification actually possible?

Comment: What do you mean by $X(R(Y,Z))$? $R(Y,Z)$ isn't a function but a $(1,1)$ tensor.

Comment: @Didier I think she means the tensor $R$ evaluated on the vector fields $Y$ and $Z$. She's using the tensor formula for the Lie derivative.

Comment: @GuPe Yes, and $R(Y,Z)$ is a $(1,1)$ tensor, that takes a vector field $T$ and gives another one $R(Y,Z)T$. I am a bit suspicious about the last equality, also I didn't check it my hand.

Comment: @Didier it seems OP got her notation mixed up. The formula she gives is consistent if you interpret $R$ as the Ricci tensor. I think this is the only way that equation makes sense so I believe that is what she meant.

Comment: @GuPe Seems reasonable, didn't thought of that

Comment: @Didier sorry, I did mix up my notation. GuPe is right, I have made the corresponding edits.

Comment: What is the final formula you are aiming at? I doubt there is a formula independent of $X$.

Comment: @Deane I am aiming for an expression I can plug into the formula I derived in my other question on Math SO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433694/does-the-conformal-factor-satisfy-some-equation-independent-of-the-vector-field 

I believe I can simplify that further to $(n-1) \nabla_a \nabla_b \Omega = \square \Omega g_{ab} - 2 X^d \nabla_d R_{ab} - 2 \Omega R_{ab}$. Solving for $\nabla_X \text{Rc}$ shows that an $X$ independent formula for this quantity exists, but I want to express the first identity without $X$.